# ClickListener for Composite Widget

Tags: java, gwt, onclick, listener

I have a composite widget made of a textbox and a custom widget, which are then added to a verticalPanel. I created this custom widget using Raphael JS.

Now i want this Composite widget to recognize both click event and also the ctrl event. I tried implementing clicklistener in both the classes with no fruitful results.

here is the code lay-out:

**This class creates the custom widget from Raphael JS:**

```
public class CustomShapeRet extends RaphaelJSWidget{

    public CustomShapeRet(){
        super();
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 20);

        r.attr("stroke", "black");
        r.attr("stroke-width", "5");
    }
}
```

**This class here creates the composite widget:**

```
public class Test extends Composite{

    public Test(){
        TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
        t1.setSize("100px", "20px");
        t1.setText("Hi");
        t1.setTitle("textbox");

        CustomShapeRet r = new CustomShapeRet();
        r.setTitle("rec");

        VerticalPanel v1 = new VerticalPanel();
        v1.setStyleName("vertical");
        v1.add(r);
        v1.add(t1);     
        initWidget(v1);
    }
}
```

Question:
    Is there a way to get this working? and what would be your recommendation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement HasClickHandler interface in your "Test" composite widget.It will force you to implement addClickHandler method.Then you can add clickHandler.You can implement the following  all iterfaces depends on your requirementHasAllFocusHandlers, HasAllKeyHandlers, HasAllMouseHandlers. If you want to add click listners for CustomShapeRet  then implement the interfaces there also.For sample code Look at the following thread:

[How do I add MouseEvents to an AbsolutePanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512692/how-do-i-add-mouseevents-to-an-absolutepanel/1512885#1512885)

Just try this.I dont have any idea about RaphaelJSWidget.

```
public class CustomShapeRet extends RaphaelJSWidget implements HasClickHandler{

public CustomShapeRet(){
    super();
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 20);

    r.attr("stroke", "black");
    r.attr("stroke-width", "5");
}

   public HandlerRegistration addMouseOutHandler(MouseOutHandler handler) {  
       return addDomHandler(handler, MouseOutEvent.getType());  
     }  
}
```

I am assuming that your RaphelJSWidget class extends Widget class.If it is true you can add click handler.It should work.

Comment: RaphaelJSWidget is a class that converts the underlying Raphael javascript to widgets. I need to draw shapes therefore i am using this. I got this idea from hydro4ge project. Here is the link: http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2009/09/hydro4ge-paas-built-with-gwt.html
Now i believe that problem i am facing is because of this raphael, as i am not sure on how to add mouse events to the raphael canvas. Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i have RaphelJSWidget class extending Widget, but for some reason it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the `Composite` in a [`FocusPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html), instead of `VerticalPanel`? (you can put the `VerticalPanel` in the `FocusPanel`, if you need the layout, but make sure that `FocusPanel` is the one you call `initWidget` on) Then you can just add a `ClickHandler` to that panel and voila. `FocusPanel` also implements `HasAllKeyHandlers`, meaning you get KeyDown/UpHandlers, etc too.